# Poetry skipping dependencies with both lower and upper bounds as "Invalid Constraint"

Tags: versioning, python-packaging, python-poetry, pyproject.toml

I am working on a project (let's call it `X`) which depends on another public package. Let's call it `A`. Package `A` has the following dependencies in the `requirements.txt` file

```
package-a>=6.1.0<7.0.0
package-b>=10.2.0<11.0.0
package-c>=1.0.4<2.0.0
package-d>=1.1.0<2.0.0
```

The `pyproject.toml` of package `X` is given below

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "X"
version = "1.0.0"
description = "Project X"
packages = [{include = "X"}]

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.8"
A = "1.0.0"
B = "12.0.0"

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

When I do a `poetry lock`, I see that the pacakges with both upper and lower bounds are being skipped

```
Updating dependencies
Resolving dependencies... (0.4s)
Invalid constraint (package-a (>=6.1.0<7.0.0)) found in A-1.0.0 dependencies, skipping
Invalid constraint (package-b (>=10.2.0<11.0.0)) found in A-1.0.0 dependencies, skipping
Invalid constraint (package-c (>=1.0.4<2.0.0)) found in A-1.0.0 dependencies, skipping
Invalid constraint (package-d (>=1.1.0<2.0.0)) found in A-1.0.0 dependencies, skipping
Resolving dependencies... (0.8s)
```

The same packages are missing in the `poetry.lock` file and hence NOT being installed when I do `poetry install`.
Any pointers on how to solve this issue ? I couldn't find any information in https://python-poetry.org/docs/dependency-specification/

Comment: Shouldn't there be a comma `,` somewhere in there? Something like `>=6.1.0,<7.0.0`) maybe?

Comment: As @sinoroc pointed out, it looks like the constraints in package A are not correctly defined. I looked at the requirements.txt of a couple of other public libraries and they seem to have a `,` in the constraints.

Comment: @sinoroc: Please move your comment to an answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems to me like a comma `,` is missing to delimit the parts of the version specifiers of `A`'s dependencies. For example it should read something like `>=6.1.0,<7.0.0` (instead of `>=6.1.0<7.0.0`).

> A version specifier consists of a series of version clauses, separated by commas.

-- [*PEP 440 – Version Identification and Dependency Specification*](https://peps.python.org/pep-0440/#version-specifiers)